# JSON.stringify loses/missing fields

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

This is my code:

```
// get from ajax
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': url,
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (d) {
        data = d;

        // code here to define & calculate voteCount

        data.votes.totalVotes = voteCount;
        localStorage.setItem(url, data);
    }
    , 'error': function (msg) {
        throw new Error("Error retrieving data from " + url);
    }
});
```

After this line:

```
data.votes.totalVotes = voteCount;
```

...in the console, if I type: `data.votes.totalVotes`, I get the value I am expecting.

However, if I type: `JSON.stringify(data)`, the `totalVotes` property is not present.

Any idea why not, or how to fix it?

** note: edited because as far as I can tell this is NOT an async issue, the behaviour is present in the success callback too.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: From a first glance it looks like a problem concerning (a)sync calls, but hard to tell from the given code.

Comment: ...so set a $.ajax({/* blah blah */,success: function(data){data.totalVotes = voteCount; localStorage..... }})

Comment: thanks @SLaks, but it's async:false, so it's surely not an async issue then?

Comment: Then it's just wrong.  `async: false` freezes the browser; don't do that.

Comment: @SLaks, it has the same problem when it's in the success function.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct version of your `$.ajax` call:

```
var data
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': url,
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (d) {
        data = d;
        data.votes.totalVotes = voteCount;
        localStorage.setItem("myData", JSON.stringify(data));
    }, 'error': function (msg) {
        throw new Error("Error retrieving data from " + url);
    }
});
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. Although it might have something to do with my last edit. The property being set is not data.totalVotes, it's data.votes.totalVotes, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Updated my answer. Do you have any console.log display?

Comment: Still doesn't work. Try it! On the console at the localStorage line in your code, I do: `data.votes.totalVotes` and I can see the value in the console. If I do `JSON.stringify(data)` and look through the object, there's no `totalVotes` property at all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, I was being daft. `votes` is an array, so I was setting `totalVotes` as a property on the array, which is  fine in the object, but gets omitted when serialized.

If someone else is as daft as I am, maybe this will help.